# Don't allow the user to save data in mysql database if the input is incorrect

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, spring-roo

Hi I am doing project in Spring Roo. Where can I put restrictions that the phone number must be 10 digits? I have already put restrictions in create.jspx and in User_Roo_DbManaged.aj but it doesn't work.
it accepts letters and shorter input.

create.jspx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/jquery/form/fields" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/jquery/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <form:create id="fc_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User" modelAttribute="user" path="/users" render="${empty dependencies}" z="wGrfaSchPJDWXlsq1jiCSRc0pAA=">
        <field:simple field="emergencies" id="c_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User_emergencies" messageCode="entity_reference_not_managed" messageCodeAttribute="Emergency" z="96v/orisk+QZ0UvamFbdCmNUM9g="/>
        <field:select field="typeId" id="c_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User_typeId" itemValue="id" items="${usertypes}" path="/usertypes" z="cuXEuKQFS8VdksWWbETwOj+Ps4k="/>
        <field:input field="name" id="c_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User_name" required="true" z="AvB38b/End0hXemXNC8GrbD8SAw="/>
        <field:input field="email" id="c_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User_email" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_email" z="OGADRfESfWyp/4F216swLnNdyoQ="/>
        <field:input field="username" id="c_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User_username" required="true" z="MiEOzhgH466ktY7pKT/tYMLt5S0="/>
        <field:input field="password" id="c_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User_password" required="true" z="kEW4oQdeXWi+JyIwdUJkmMKHYII=" type="password"/>
        <field:input field="phone" id="c_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User_phone" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_number" max="10" min="10" z="k42Av41wIfhbInJmZhCY/WbW+h4="/>
        <field:input field="year" id="c_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User_year" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_number" max="4" min="4" z="HL+hSR+nz8/34t6nn2HXLRJaIyA="/>
        <field:input field="active" id="c_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User_active" required="true" validationMessageCode="field_invalid_integer" max="1" min="1" z="wMEcOQjcrIJKY5RQ7mQ4/Uu9Ago="/>
        <field:input field="description" id="c_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User_description" required="true" z="6TJHmWCAvkCtONvKOBHftLCMtso="/>
    </form:create>
    <form:dependency dependencies="${dependencies}" id="d_edu_ndnu_capstone_domain_User" render="${not empty dependencies}" z="Do0kIZAQM8ZWzWNlt1c/uMANnj4="/>
</div>
```

User_Roo_DbManaged.aj

```
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. THIS FILE IS MANAGED BY SPRING ROO.
// You may push code into the target .java compilation unit if you wish to edit any member(s).

package edu.ndnu.capstone.domain;

import edu.ndnu.capstone.domain.Emergency;
import edu.ndnu.capstone.domain.User;
import edu.ndnu.capstone.domain.UserType;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

privileged aspect User_Roo_DbManaged {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId")
    private Set<Emergency> User.emergencies;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private UserType User.typeId;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 256)
    @NotNull
    private String User.name;

    @Column(name = "email", length = 256, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String User.email;

    @Column(name = "username", length = 150, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String User.username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotNull
    private String User.password;

    @Column(name = "phone", length = 10, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String User.phone;

    @Column(name = "year", length = 4)
    @NotNull
    private String User.year;

    @Column(name = "active", length = 1)
    @NotNull
    private Integer User.active;

    @Column(name = "created", updatable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(style = "MM")
    private Calendar User.created = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    @Column(name = "description", length = 1024)
    @NotNull
    private String User.description;

    public Set<Emergency> User.getEmergencies() {
        return emergencies;
    }

    public void User.setEmergencies(Set<Emergency> emergencies) {
        this.emergencies = emergencies;
    }

    public UserType User.getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    public void User.setTypeId(UserType typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    public String User.getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void User.setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String User.getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void User.setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String User.getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void User.setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String User.getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void User.setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String User.getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void User.setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String User.getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void User.setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Integer User.getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void User.setActive(Integer active) {
        if(active==0 || active==1)
        this.active = active;
        else
             this.active = 2;
    }

    public Calendar User.getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void User.setCreated(Calendar created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String User.getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void User.setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't modify any `.aj` because Spring Roo will overwrite your changes next time you run it. To customize your field you have to move its declaration into related `.java` file (we call it *push-in*).

To set the field validation, Roo uses the [JSR-303 specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303), using the [Hibernate validation](http://hibernate.org/validator/) as implementation.

So, to archive it, try:

1. *Push-in* the `phone` declaration into `User.java` and add `javax.validation.constraints.Size` annotation:

   ```
   public class User {

      @Column(name = "phone", length = 10, unique = true)
      @NotNull
      @Size(max=10,min=10)
      private String phone;
   }
   ```
2. Run Spring Roo console.

After that,  Roo will:

1. remove `phone` definition from `User_Roo_DbManaged.aj`
2. create the getter and setter on `User_Roo_bean.aj`
3. Update `User` related *.jspx*

Note that `@Column` definition refers to database declaration. Any other field validation you should use the `javax.validation.constraints.*` annotations or create yours ([here you have an example](http://goldenpackagebyanuj.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/custom-jsr-303-validation-using-constraintValidator.html))

Good luck!